# HTML: How to remove line spacing from PRE tag

Tags: html, jlabel

When the text is displayed from the follwing HTML there is a large space between the two line. How do i remove that space?

```html
<pre style="font-family:arial;color:191970;font-size:10px;line-height:.1;">
Line 1 with one tab at the end
</pre>
<pre style="font-family:arial;color:191970;font-size:10px;line-height:.1;">
Line 2 with one tab at the end
</pre>
```

**Why i am using  tag?** 
I place 2 tabs at the end of each line thats why i am using this tag

Comment: I don't see any large spaces.  I see the two lines right on top of each other: http://jsfiddle.net/LbnZ4/

Comment: Same here. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @robmayoff I am assigning this html to JLabel, i also tag that but some one remove that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using two `<pre/>` tags for two lines. so you need to manage margine and paddings for the `<pre/>` tag. `line-height` is not enough. and remember to set the `line-height` in `em` values and set the initial font size and line-height at the document level as well.

Answer (score 3):

by default pre tag is displayed as block, that is the reason. To over come this   use following code in CSS

```
 pre 
    {
    display: inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- here is a complete example pretty print with more space between lines-->
<!-- be sure to pass a json string not an json object -->
<!-- use line-height to increase or decrease spacing between json lines -->

  <style  type="text/css">
    .preJsonTxt{
      font-size: 18px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 200%;
    }
    .boxedIn{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>

<div class="boxedIn">
     <h3>Configuration Parameters</h3>
     <pre id="jsonCfgParams" class="preJsonTxt">{{ cfgParams }}</pre>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
$( document ).ready(function()
{
 $(formatJson);

 <!-- this will do a pretty print on the json cfg params      -->
 function formatJson() {
    var element = $("#jsonCfgParams");
    var obj = JSON.parse(element.text());
    element.html(JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2));
}
});
</script>
```